# Lt. Morales Mana Control

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I am trying Morales this week. Her single-target healing (Q) is pretty impressive, but it also makes her hungry for mana.

Should I keep using Q to my teammates, or I only need to use it when someone urgently needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It depends on the situation!

Sounds pretty boring, but that's how it is. Some general guidelines:

#### When you should heal

- **In teamfights (obviously).** Her single-target heal is extremly strong if unanswered. It doesn't matter if you are out-of-mana after the fight if you wiped the enemy team. Make sure to choose the right heal target! (not really the question here, so I leave it like that. I can add some sentences for that if needed)
- **When you have full mana.** Every hero regenerates mana on his own. If you run around with full mana, you are wasting this regeneration. Of course you can't do much if noone is near you to heal but if there is, just go for it. However, don't burn too much mana in a situation like this, only use such an amount of mana that you can regenerate until you are needed at the next objective/teamfight. This also applies if you tapped a well (for hp) and the mana regeneration you got from it exceeds your maximum mana. Don't let it go to waste!
- **When an ally is low on hp,** no time left to hearthstone, healing fountain is on cooldown and he is needed at an objective/ teamfight. If one or more allies are low on hp when a fight is just around the corner, you have to heal them. Even if it means that you run low on mana. You can easily heal multiple allies back up with your mana-pool, so use it. Being out-of-mana is better than having half of your team < 1000 hp.
- **When you are about tp hearthstone.** Fairly simple: There is no reason to save your mana when you are going back to the base.

#### When you should not heal

- **The heal target has strong self-heal.** Healing a Muradin who is about to use Stoneform is usually pointless. Your heal is better used on someone else or not at all to save mana. Also applies if your ally just tapped a well.
- **The heal target is about to heartstone.** If you see someone with low mana and low hp, going back into a fort, don't heal. He is going to Hearthstone back and your heal is wasted.
- **The heal target is at around 80% hp**. Unless you have full mana (see abovee), save it. Every hero regenerates hp over time, so usually they will be full hp on their own at the next fight.
- **The heal target is dying anyway.** Yes, you are a support and you wanna save your allies from dying. However, sometimes there is just no hope for someone to survive, so you might as well save your mana. It is a hard call to make, but you will learn to recognize those moments with the time. You might get flamed for not healing, just ignore it. A lot of people will blame the support for everything to cover their own mistakes. Always keep in mind: **You can't heal stupid.** There might be some merit in delaying the death of you ally though, so he can do some more damage and maybe get a kill first, so you trade even. As I said it all depends on the situation. But if he is unable to deal damage because he is stunlocked, just let him die.

### Conclusion

As you see, there are a lot of factors involved in this. Playing support is more than being a simple healbot, especially on mana-hungry heroes like morales. However, if in doubt, heal. **Better safe than sorry! One kill can decide the game in the lategame!**

Comment: Thank you DenkerAffe, you are really a good support! Some of the suggestions above are not only for Morales but other supports too. In the team fight, my priority is dying targeted assassin >> Tank >> other supports, is this correct?

Comment: @JayWong I am actually a pretty bad support, I don't like this role at all ^^. But glad I could help you! You are right, most of the tips apply to other supports as well, mana conserservation as support is nothing special to morales. You are right about healing assasins first, you need to save your damage-dealers. However, healing tanks is something you usually want to avoid because they have a high hp-regeneration on their own and other defensive tools. If they are not in danger of dying, don't heal them. You are usually happy if your enemies are blowing all their CD's on your tank.